# Sum the first column in AWK but gives readable number

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I created the following awk cli in order to sum the first column in the file

example of the file.txt

```
0
15.5
15.5
15.5
15.2
14.9
14.9
15.2
15.3
15.4
15.5
15.5
15.6
15.6
15.7
15.8
15.8
15.8
15.8
15.8
15.8
.
.
.
```

but `awk` gives the number --> `3.70747e+07` , that isn't readable

```
awk  '{sum+=$1;} END{print sum;}'  file.txt
3.70747e+07
```

is it possible to change the `awk` syntax in order to get readable number as  370747.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace print with printf like:

```
awk '{sum+=$1;} END{printf("%f\n",sum);}' file.txt
```